# if и else в python

Tags: python, if

Не понимаю как сделать, чтобы писалась ошибка, когда выбрали цифру меньше 1 или больше 10, поставил if перепробовал все значения, ничего не работает...

```
mobile_phone_list = ["","realme XT", "Iphone 11", "Honor 20", "Samsung A51", "Iphone 6", "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8", "Honor 9 Lite", "Samsung A21", "Iphone XR", "realme X"]

print("Cписок моделей телефонов:", mobile_phone_list)

len(mobile_phone_list)-1 

for i in mobile_phone_list:
    len(mobile_phone_list)-1 
print("Всего моделей телефонов:",len(mobile_phone_list)-1)

print("Вам достался телефон в подарок, введите любую цифру от 1 до 10: ")

print(mobile_phone_list[int(input())])
if mobile_phone_list == "0":
    print("Ошибка. Введите любую цифру от 1 до 10.")

print("Поздравляем, вы получили этот телефон абсолютно бесплатно!", )
```

Comment: Вам бы учебник какой-нибудь прочитать. Приведённый код бессмысленный чуть более, чем полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы проверить условие, тебе необходимо создать переменную и записать результат получения индекса в неё:

```
index = int(input())
print(mobile_phone_list[index])
if index == 0:
    print("Ошибка. Введите любую цифру от 1 до 10.")
```

Также обрати внимание, что запись `len(mobile_phone_list)-1` не делает ничего, так как результат никуда не записывается.

Comment: Для того, чтобы разобраться в теме, советую посмотреть https://pythontutor.ru/